# defect with jquery modal dialog after scrolldown and refresh in IE

Tags: modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I found a bug (or feature) on the behavior of the jquery modal dialog in IE (Firefox works properly).

In IE9 (not sure about other IE versions), it positions the dialog at the top of a scrollable page **outside of the users viewport** if invoked from the bottom of the page. This is easily reproducible in IE from the [jqueryui dialog demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal).

1. Navigate there,
2. close the dialog the comes up upon page load,
3. scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page,
4. and then hit refresh.

The user won't see the modal dialog and only the dimmed overlay as a suttle hint that there's a dialog at the top and to scroll up and close/address it. The IE page will flash for a split second showing the dialog upon load and then snaps back to the previous location at the bottom where the dialog is out of view.

I did see the other posts related to this about using `onclick="return false;"` in an anchor tag if invoked from there, but this example is not from an anchor so I'm not sure how that would work here or if it even applies.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a styling issue that will cause IE to cause this issue with the jqueryui dialog. If your body or html is styled to have a height of 100% the dialog always displays with a fixed position from the top.

Comment: I just tried editing the JQuery default dialog example by setting a fixed height of 2000px for the html and body, but it exhibits the same behavior.